# Date field ouput when date is not given

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

Please consider the following MWE using the package `biblatex-apa`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
    @misc{website,
      title = {Wikipedia},
      url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/},
      urldate = {2013-08-27}
    }
    }
    \end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}


    % Set the values for the bibliography
    \usepackage[
        style=apa,
        backend=biber
    ]{biblatex}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    % Set language
    \usepackage[british]{babel}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

    \addbibresource{mybib.bib}

    \begin{document}

    \cite{website}

    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

I noticed that the output of the in line citation for the *date* field is `n.d.` but in the bibliography is `nodate`. Is it possible to also output `n.d.` in the bibliography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `biblatex-apa` style defines the label date as follows

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

The `labeldate` is used when there is no date for a publication, thus one has to modify the  definition above as follows:

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \literal{n.d.}
}
```

[image]